# how to skip first line of csv file data using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, csv

I am using datatables to print the csv file data. The CSV file consists of data .this is an  exmple data file.

```
name,city,category,discount
surya,gnt,all,10%
surya,gnt,all,10%
surya,gnt,all,10%
surya,gnt,all,10%
surya,gnt,all,10%
```

I want to skip first line of data . How to stop displaying th first line in my datatable. And my code is`

```js
//saving csv file to firebase
            $('#save-csv').bind('click', function() {
     if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)        {
   var file = document.getElementById('files').files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsText(file);
     reader.onload = function(event){
    var csv = event.target.result;
    var data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);
    var csvObj = {}
    for(key in data){
     csvObj[key] = {};
     csvObj[key].name = data[key][0];
     csvObj[key].city = data[key][1];
     csvObj[key].category = data[key][2];
     csvObj[key].discount = data[key][3];
    }
    console.log(csvObj);
    $scope.csvStores.stores = csvObj;
    $scope.csvStores.$save().then(function(res){
     console.info(res);
    }).catch(function(err){
     console.error(err);
    });
    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
    swal(
     'Saved',
     'Successfully Saved',
     'success'
    )
        }
      }else {
   
   }
      });
```

Comment: you are reading only 1 line and skip that line too?

Answer (score 0):

Before you iterate over your data you should somehow remove/skip the first line.
In my opinion it is better to remove, cause if you would like to use later this array, then you have to skip again.
I have two ideas:

before the iteration call:`data = data.shift();`
based on this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp
This will remove the first element.

Or if you are using lodash, than you can easily call `data = _.tail(data);` based on this: https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#tail